# How can I add a button like facebook messenger's Status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

How i can add header like this inside my app and receive the touch event also control over it to hide/show ?

[image]

Comment: Add a simple UIView to your UIViewController with a frame of something like (0,0,320,40), add a label and a UITapGestureRecognizer to it. Do whatever you want on the tap.

Comment: Yours answer is in this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1

Comment: The simple secrets of the century ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something to work on.

I made a new project for iOS 7, with a single ViewController. Here is the storyboard :

[image: Storyboard]

I added a simple `UIView` at the top, a `UINavigationBar` just under it, and a large `UIView` taking the remaining space. This last view is where you should put your content.

Now here is the ViewController code :

**ViewController.h :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *littleView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
- (IBAction)toggleLittleView:(id)sender;

@end
```

`littleView` is the view behind the status bar, `navbar` is the navigation bar, `mainView` is the content view, and `toggleLittleview` is linked to the button in the nav bar.

**ViewController.m :**

```
@implementation ViewController {

    BOOL isVisible;
    CGFloat statusBarOffset;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setting initial values
    isVisible = YES;
    statusBarOffset = 20;

    // Adding a gesture recognizer to littleView
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [_littleView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

// Linked to the nav bar button
- (IBAction)toggleLittleView:(id)sender {

    // If littleView is not on screen, show it before animation
    if (!isVisible) {
        _littleView.hidden = !_littleView.hidden;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    }

    // Animate to the new frames
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{

                         _littleView.frame = CGRectOffset(_littleView.frame, 0, isVisible ? -(_littleView.frame.size.height-statusBarOffset) : (_littleView.frame.size.height-statusBarOffset));
                         _navBar.frame = CGRectMake(_navBar.frame.origin.x, _littleView.frame.origin.y + _littleView.frame.size.height, _navBar.frame.size.width, _navBar.frame.size.height);
                         CGFloat offSet = isVisible ? self.view.frame.size.height - _navBar.frame.size.height + statusBarOffset : self.view.frame.size.height - _navBar.frame.size.height - _littleView.frame.size.height + statusBarOffset;
                         _mainView.frame = CGRectMake(_mainView.frame.origin.x, _navBar.frame.origin.y + _navBar.frame.size.height, _mainView.frame.size.width, offSet);

                         isVisible = !isVisible;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         // If view is not visible after animation, hide it
                         if (!isVisible) {
                             _littleView.hidden = !_littleView.hidden;
                             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
                         }
                     }];
}

// Do stuff on tap
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap {

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"You tapped !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

@end
```

**WARNING**

This code is not perfect, but it basically replicates the effect you're looking for. You should work on it to make it behave as you wish. Also, this was implemented in a simple `UIViewController`, **not** embed in a `UINavigationController`, with a navigation bar I added manually. This code won't work in a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` embed in a `UINavigationController`. It does not use autolayout, which you definitely should use under iOS 6/7.

Here is gif preview :

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with a navigation controller, right?

Comment: You'll need to work a bit on the code but it should be adaptable

Comment: The point is that you need a UIToolBar in order to place a UIView between the statusbar and the toolbar using Storyboard IB. Using a View that's embedded in a UINavigationController you cannot just place a view between them, or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct. But I'm pretty sure this is doable in code with a bit of work.